Camera preview not visible on mobile browser, but present on the desktop
I am making a web app, where I want the users to take a photo. I did a sample script with html, css and javascript. It works perfectly on the desktop, but not on the mobile browsers. The problem is with camera preview. I am allowed to take a picture, but somehow preview is not visible. Its certainly not the issue with permissions, as as I said I can take a photo. The problem is that I don't see camera preview on any of the mobile browsers .                                                                         Any suggestions why it not working?  Here's my code:
<title>Camera Demo</title>\/head>
<body>
  <div id="cameraContainer">
   <video id="cameraStream" autoplay></video>
   <button id="shutterButton">Take Photo</button
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>

<script>
const video = document.getElementById('cameraStream');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const shutterButton = document.getElementById('shutterButton');

    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(function(stream) {
          video.srcObject = stream;
          video.play();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
          alert("Error accessing camera: " + err.message);
        });
    } else {
      alert('Sorry, your browser does not support getUserMedia');
    }
    
    shutterButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      
      const capturedImage = new Image();
      capturedImage.src = dataUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(capturedImage);

 });
 </script>
</body>

I tried to take a photo on the mobile browser and it works perfectly. What I want to achieve to have the same functionality on mobile browsers.
